# Can't select vertex to use function "E". Function "E" Falling

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTIQ7KNM4XI

But when i do the function "E" (extrude) and stop and try to extrude again, it dosn't work correctly.
[image]

Comment: "...doesn't work correctly" isn't exactly specific. Care to elaborate? Please use the edit link below your question to add more information.

Comment: A possible cause for this might be that you have a vertex inbetween those you selected, that you did not select. If this is correct, then if you selected those vertices before extruding, the edge inbetween would not have been orange (An edge normally gets selected if you select the start and end vertices). If this inbetween vertex is very close or exactly on the vertices you selected you could try "remove doubles" to solve that and then try again...